# get the next highest number value if decimal exists

Tags: java

i am wondering how to get output like `17` if i provide input like `16.001` in java programming?

I tried this `(int)Math.ceil(168/10);` but it did not worked for me. Please help me. I want 17 output but it was giving 16.

**Expected output**

```
String inputval="16.01";
int ouput ;

//output should come as 17
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

168/10 will return an integer with value 16. You need to cast one of the integers to a double like this:

```
(int)Math.ceil((double)168/10);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
double inputval=16.01;
int ouput = ( (int) Math.ceil (inputval) );
```

//Now output should be 17

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
String inputval="16.01";
int val = (int) Math.ceil(Double.valueOf(inputval));
```

Comment: Please explain how your suggested code works, so future users can understand your solution better.